# How do you send messages from a different address using Gmail and Java?

Tags: java, smtp, gmail, smtp-auth

I'm using Java to send messages from Gmail with [Apache Commons Email](http://commons.apache.org/email/), but it seems like it doesn't allow me to send messages from an address different from the one that I use to authenticate.

How do you send messages from a different address using Gmail and Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you are looking for an SMTP server which will let you send a message by spoofing the From MIME header. Well, if you can't find a hosted SMTP server online, you can always [install one locally](http://www.google.com/search?q=free%20smtp%20server) on your box. This will allow you to modify the email address of the sender to make it appear as if it is coming from gmail.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware you can't. That is what is called relaying. Relaying is what the spammers use to send mail pretending to be whoever. Its a security hole. If you want to send as someone else you need to create another account.

Answer (score 0):

> How do you send messages from a different address using Gmail and Java?

For gmail, you most likely can't ... for obvious reasons.

In the Java case, whether you can or can't do this depends on the mail server that your Java application connects to.  A mail server typically *can be* configured to allow this, but it has obvious issues so a responsible mail server admin is not going to allow this, except in controlled circumstances.